# Parsing a Matrix that has three columns (Date, Parameter, Result) into a matrix that has a column for each parameter at specified date R

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, reshape

I have a matrix that has 3 columns and 47,772 rows. Within the rows there are 64 parameters.

Currently the data frame looks like:

```
SAMPLE_DATE PARAMETER   RESULT  
8/2/1954    Alkalinity, total as CaCO3(mg/L)    112.5  
8/2/1954    Depth, Secchi disk depth(m) 2.44  
8/2/1954    Nutrient-nitrogen as N(mg/L)    0.87  
8/2/1954    Phosphorus as P(mg/L)   0.001  
8/2/1954    Sulfate as SO4(mg/L)    11  
3/7/1962    Alkalinity, total as CaCO3(mg/L)    140  
3/7/1962    Alkalinity, total as CaCO3(mg/L)    320  
3/7/1962    Alkalinity, total as CaCO3(mg/L)    130  
3/7/1962    Ammonia-nitrogen as N(mg/L) 0.02  
3/7/1962    Ammonia-nitrogen as N(mg/L) 0.26  
3/7/1962    Ammonia-nitrogen as N(mg/L) 0.02  
3/7/1962    Apparent color(PCU) 10  
3/7/1962    Apparent color(PCU) 10
....
```

and I want transform it into something that looks like:

```
Date          Alkalinity, total as CaCO3(mg/L)      Depth, Secchi disk depth(m).....etc  
8/2/1954             112.5                                    2.44              ..... etc
```

note: not every date has every parameter

Any Ideas?

Comment: How do you propose dealing with duplicated dates+parameter combinations (for example rows with `3/7/1962  Alkalinity,...`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be (sort of) a contingency table (zeros if no value and teh sum of values when there are overlapping category values):

```
 xtabs(RESULT~ SAMPLE_DATE+PARAMETER, data=dat)

              PARAMETER
SAMPLE_DATE    Alkalinity, total as CaCO3(mg/L) Ammonia-nitrogen as N(mg/L)
      3/7/1962                          590.000                       0.300
      8/2/1954                          112.500                       0.000
              PARAMETER
SAMPLE_DATE    Apparent color(PCU) Depth, Secchi disk depth(m)
      3/7/1962              20.000                       0.000
      8/2/1954               0.000                       2.440
              PARAMETER
SAMPLE_DATE    Nutrient-nitrogen as N(mg/L) Phosphorus as P(mg/L)
      3/7/1962                        0.000                 0.000
      8/2/1954                        0.870                 0.001
              PARAMETER
SAMPLE_DATE    Sulfate as SO4(mg/L)
      3/7/1962                0.000
      8/2/1954               11.000
```

If you have a different desire than the sum() of repeated categories then the `tapply` function can deliver. E.g. with the `mean` as the target function:

```
with( dat, tapply(RESULT, list( SAMPLE_DATE, PARAMETER), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE))
             Alkalinity, total as CaCO3(mg/L) Ammonia-nitrogen as N(mg/L) Apparent color(PCU) Depth, Secchi disk depth(m)
    3/7/1962                         196.6667                         0.1                  10                          NA
    8/2/1954                         112.5000                          NA                  NA                        2.44
             Nutrient-nitrogen as N(mg/L) Phosphorus as P(mg/L) Sulfate as SO4(mg/L)
    3/7/1962                           NA                    NA                   NA
    8/2/1954                         0.87                 0.001                   11
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach. I've added a "time" variable since there are duplicated "SAMPLE_DATE" + "PARAMETER" combinations.

```
library(reshape2)        # for dcast
library(splitstackshape) # for getanID
x2 <- getanID(x, id.vars = c("SAMPLE_DATE", "PARAMETER"))
dcast(x2, .id + SAMPLE_DATE ~ PARAMETER, value.var = "RESULT")
#   .id SAMPLE_DATE Alkalinity, total as CaCO3(mg/L) Ammonia-nitrogen as N(mg/L)
# 1   1    3/7/1962                            140.0                        0.02
# 2   1    8/2/1954                            112.5                          NA
# 3   2    3/7/1962                            320.0                        0.26
# 4   3    3/7/1962                            130.0                        0.02
#   Apparent color(PCU) Depth, Secchi disk depth(m) Nutrient-nitrogen as N(mg/L)
# 1                  10                          NA                           NA
# 2                  NA                        2.44                         0.87
# 3                  10                          NA                           NA
# 4                  NA                          NA                           NA
#   Phosphorus as P(mg/L) Sulfate as SO4(mg/L)
# 1                    NA                   NA
# 2                 0.001                   11
# 3                    NA                   NA
# 4                    NA                   NA
```

---

As above, but with the "data.table" package:

```
library(data.table)
packageVersion("data.table")
# [1] ‘1.8.11’
DT <- data.table(x)
DT[, .id := sequence(.N), by = list(SAMPLE_DATE, PARAMETER)]
dcast.data.table(DT, .id + SAMPLE_DATE ~ PARAMETER, value.var="RESULT")
```

---

If you don't want separate rows for duplicated combinations, you will have to `aggregate` the data in some way first.